# Mysql SUM with GROUP BY and WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have three tables and added joins to reference the where clause and limit the results.

Without the where clause the SUM and GROUP BY works well over all the table entries. But if i try to limit the results to the tool.id it does not work.

**orders**

```
ID | tool_id  | 
1  |    1     | 
2  |    1     |  
3  |    1     |
4  |    2     |
```

**postitions_list**

```
ID | order_id | optionindex | 
1  |    1     |  1          |  
2  |    1     |  2          |  
3  |    1     |  1          |  
4  |    2     |  4          |
```

**tools**

```
ID | Number   |
1  |   10     | 
2  |   20     |  
3  |   30     |
```

**query**

```
SELECT
orders.id,
orders.tool_id,
positions_list.order_id,
positions_list.optionindex,
tools.id,
tools.tool_number,
SUM(positions_list.optionindex) AS optionindex

FROM positions_list

LEFT JOIN orders
ON orders.id=positions_list.order_id

LEFT JOIN tools  
ON  tools.id=orders.tool_id

WHERE
tools.id = :id 

GROUP BY positions_list.optionindex
```

What i need is

**query results based on given tool.id**

```
ID | tool_id | optionindex | optionindex 
1  |  1      | 1           |  2
2  |  1      | 2           |  1
3  |  1      | 3           |  0   
4  |  1      | 4           |  0
```

---

In addition the next step would be to get the optionindex.content

**optionindex**

```
ID | content  | 
1  |  Value1  | 
2  |  Value2  |  
3  |  Value3  |  
4  |  Value4  |
```

So the query result i final need is:

**query results based on given tool.id**

```
ID | tool_id | optionindex | optionindex | optionindex.content
1  |  1      | 1           |  2          | Value1
2  |  1      | 2           |  1          | Value2
3  |  1      | 3           |  0          | Value3
4  |  1      | 4           |  0          | Value4
```

Comment: You can't do this `WHERE
tools.id = :id ` if tools is an outer joined table (left/right/full).  The condition must be placed as AND criteria on the join `LEFT JOIN tools  
ON  tools.id=orders.tool_id and tools.id = :id` or the LEFT join is treated as a inner join.  Alternatively you have to do this: `WHERE
tools.id = :id  or tools.id is null` but this is inefficient as the OR negates index usage.

Comment: Thanks, but there is maybe another problem in my query because the result is still not as required. It SUM still all entries from table, not limited by tool.id.

Comment: group by should list all columns not in the aggregates unless the value of those columns is identical for all records selected.  Best form is to always include all columns not in an aggregate in your group by

Comment: This question is relatively clear, but because I often answer from my phone, I can only provide support with my limited time if you create a dbfiddle for me to test with.  If you have already solved this problem, please post an answer and accept it so that this page is deemed resolved.